# Regular expression to match mixed list of ranges and number list

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to validate a String that represents a list of ranges as known from the print dialog where you indicate which pages to print. Examples:

- 1
- 1-10
- 1,20
- 1-5,10
- 1-3,9-11

I guess anything that is not "finished" is invalid, such as:

- 1-
- 1,
- ,3
- 1-4,
- 1,2,4-

As you can guess - I am failing at it ;)

Any help is highly appreciated

Comment: Can you add an example of string that you would consider as invalid ?
Also, what did you try ?

Comment: I added some invalid examples upon your request.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try the regex `(\d+(\-\d+)?(,(?!$))?)+`, like:

```
String str = "1-1,12";
System.out.println(str.matches("(\\d+(\\-\\d+)?(,(?!$))?)+"));
```

Where:

`\d+` 1 or more digit

`(\\-\\d+)?` followed or not by `-` and 1 or more digit

`(,(?!$))?` and all the above is followed or not by ',' (but not as the last position of the string - `(?!$)` is negative look-ahead of the end of the string)

`+` says, that all above must be presented at least one time

Comment: Hii Stanislav, Thanks for your answer and the explanations! It seems working quite nicely, except for a case as follows: `1-3,9-11`. To be fair, I did not put it as a possible example above , but I add it now ;)

Comment: @dmeu just change it to `(\d+(\-\d+)?(,(?!$))?)+` and it will work.

Comment: @dmeu updated the answer)

Comment: whew. thanks! I would not have figured this out!